# Skype4py - Skypebot if statements [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, if-statement, bots, skype, statements

I have a (hopefully) simple question about a boolean function.
I am trying to set up a simple auto replier, but for some reason it returns no errors but just does not work. I am not sure why, it seems like it's not registering that I have set afk to equal True. I'm stuck. Any help?

```
    afk = False #set to default as False
    if Status == 'SENT' or (Status == 'RECEIVED'):
        if Message.Body.lower() == '!afk on':
            afk = True #set "on"
            Message.Chat.SendMessage("AFK ON")

        elif Message.Body.lower() == '!afk off':
            afk = False #turn off
            Message.Chat.SendMessage("AFK OFF")

    if afk == True and (Status == 'SENT' or Status == 'RECEIVED'): #if its true AND in a message
        if 'myname' in Message.Body.lower():
            Message.Chat.SendMessage("I'm not here. Be back soon!")
```

Comment: why is (Status == 'RECEIVED') in brackets?

Comment: @ChrisProsser That does not affect the result

Comment: No real reason, works though. I receive "AFK ON" in chat, but then typing 'myname' does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right, so if `afk` stays `False` is because the line where it gets to `True` is never executed.

Try adding `print` statements at each conditional case, printing the `STATUS` and the value `Message.Body.lower()`, so you are able to see these values at execution time.

Comment: It's receiving correctly, and setting it. But doesn't seem to be acknowledging the last bit, if it's true and it's in the message, so I think the fault lies there. http://i.imgur.com/3KDhDrX.png

Comment: Interesting, if I remove the if afk == true, and just allow it to run while printing 'afk', I can set afk to true with !afk on but when using 'myname' it returns false.

http://i.imgur.com/VpRUKqh.png

Comment: It's as if afk is not holding it's value once assigned, keeps reverting back to default

http://i.imgur.com/VPUVk8m.png

Comment: Show more code. Is this a method you are calling many times from somewehere else?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't use the bot enough to warrant looking into this anymore. Cheers.